# Selecionar e mostrar num gráfico a ultima linha de um .csv em python

Tags: python, data, csv

Tenho um pedaço de código em python que vai buscar os dados de um ficheiro .csv e depois vai mostrá-lo num gráfico. Contudo este seleciona todos os dados e eu apenas queria a ultima linha inserida no .csv . O código é este:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


with open('2112320-12.csv', 'r') as f: 
    last_line = f.readlines()[-1]
    
var = pd.read_csv("2112320-12.csv")
print(var)



x = list(var['Measure'])
y = list(var['F'])
z = list(var['G'])
x1 = list(var['H'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3)
ax[0].plot(x, y,'.')
ax[1].plot(x,z,'.')
ax[2].plot(x,x1,'.')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

No trecho onde voce le as linhas, altere para:

```
file_lines = f.readlines()
last_line = file_lines[len(file_lines) - 1]
```